# Is a question about an application running in the background on-topic (audit review)?

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

I failed a triage audit on this question: *[Disable Xcode 9 app automatically building in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46289380/disable-xcode-9-app-automatically-building-in-background)*

I flagged it as Off-topic: General Hardware/Software. Apparently Xcode 9 is a programming related application. So is a question about how a application runs for the questioner as a user on-topic, if that application is programming related?

My reasoning was that because the question was asking how to change how their machine runs an application that it was "general computing". More like a support request than a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: It's borderline. In cases like that, you should probably just leave it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add to Bill's answer here:  the software being described and the context it's being used is *solely* for development.  No general purpose application would be building code automatically in the background.

> My reasoning was that because question was asking how to change how their machine runs an application that it was "general computing".

IDEs build things in the background all the time.  Some of us love this feature.  Others don't.  We as developers know where and when to tweak and configure this setting, if it can be done.

> More like a support request than a Stack Overflow question.

I half-disagree; we allow for questions related to software for software development, and IDEs like XCode are very much related to sofware development.  I do see your point about how it feels like we're providing support for this software, though.

Answer (score 5):

Since Xcode is the IDE for Apple development, it's a tool primarily used by programmers, for programming. Configuring it is on-topic at Stack Overflow.

There might be other sites where you could also ask about it, but I think SO is the best fit, since that's where you're most likely to find other Xcode users who have run into the same kind of problem.